# Bitrix. Ссылка вида #SITE_DIR#/catalog/product/#ELEMENT_CODE# - 404

Tags: битрикс

В настройках инфоблока каталога изменил url детальной страницы с:

```
#SITE_DIR#/catalog/#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/
```

на:

```
#SITE_DIR#/catalog/product/#ELEMENT_CODE#/
```

После этого на странице каталога в режиме правки изменил настройки чпу bitrix:catalog для детальной информации с:

```
#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/
```

на:

```
product/#ELEMENT_CODE#/
```

В чём моя ошибка? Как добиться данной структуры урлов для страниц товаров?

Comment: Директория /product/ существует в директории /catalog/ ?

Comment: И в этой директории должен быть размещен компонент детальной страницы товара.

Comment: @nikolajSarry разве комплексный компонент не должен и так работать?
И ведь в такой ситуации мне придется заменить комплексный компонент на вывод разделов и товаров, так как чпу комплексного компонента будет мешать

Comment: Точно не скажу. Возможно без размещения компонента детального товара в папке /product/ и будет работать. Но без физического существования директории /product/ насколько мне помнится точно не может.

Comment: @NikolajSarry нашел в чем проблема.
Внутри комплексного компонента при вызове catalog.element не передавался раздел.
Спасибо за помощь.